# Error while installing Autoware using source code

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am relatively new to Autoware and I am trying to install it on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed ros-kinetic and followed https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/wiki/Source-Build

However, when I tried sudo ./colcon_release, it gave me the following messages:

```
steve@ubuntu:~/Documents/autoware/ros$ sudo ./colcon_releaseStarting >>> autoware_build_flags
Starting >>> autoware_msgs                           
Starting >>> autoware_config_msgs
Starting >>> tablet_socket_msgs
[7.829s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved                  
future: <Task finished coro=<_wait_and_close_fds() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:253> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.833s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_wait_and_close_fds() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:253> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.836s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved                  
future: <Task finished coro=<_wait_and_close_fds() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:253> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.839s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.840s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.841s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.842s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
--- stderr: autoware_msgs
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Failed   <<< autoware_msgs  [ Exited with code 1 ]
--- stderr: tablet_socket_msgs
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Aborted  <<< tablet_socket_msgs
--- stderr: autoware_config_msgs
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Aborted  <<< autoware_config_msgs
--- stderr: autoware_build_flags
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Aborted  <<< autoware_build_flags
[7.887s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
[7.888s] ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<_fd2callback() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py:220> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine

Summary: 0 packages finished [7.46s]
  1 package failed: autoware_msgs
  3 packages aborted: autoware_build_flags autoware_config_msgs tablet_socket_msgs
  4 packages had stderr output: autoware_build_flags autoware_config_msgs autoware_msgs tablet_socket_msgs
  136 packages not processed
```

My GCC version is 5.4.0 and env | grep ros shows:

```
steve@ubuntu:~/Documents/autoware/ros$ env | grep ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/steve/bin:/home/steve/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PWD=/home/steve/Documents/autoware/ros
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323180/error-while-installing-autoware-using-source-code/) by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, when I tried sudo ./colcon_release [..]

I'm not an autoware expert, but the only time `colcon_release` is mentioned in the instructions you link, it is not run with `sudo`. This is the section that mentions `colcon_release` (from [here](https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/wiki/Source-Build#build-with-colcon-v111-and-above)):

> #### Compile
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/Autoware/ros/
>     $ rosdep update
> ```

```
$ rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
$ ./colcon_release
```

Note the `./colcon_release` at the end. In fact, none of the build steps are run with `sudo` (and that would be something I'd expect).

I would suggest to follow the instructions and run `colcon_release` without `sudo`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on 2019-05-15**:
Thanks for your reply.

But if I run it without sudo, the following messages may show up:

```
steve@ubuntu:~/Documents/Autoware/ros$ ./colcon_release
rm: cannot remove 'build/autoware_config_msgs/colcon_command_prefix_build.sh.env': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/autoware_config_msgs/CMakeCache.txt': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'build/autoware_config_msgs/colcon_command_prefix_build.sh': Permission denied
...
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
This could be caused by your first attempt to run `colcon_release` as `root` (which is essentially what `sudo` does).

You can try to fix the situation with the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME/Documents/Autoware/ros
```

which resets all files to be owned by your own user (ie: `steve`) instead of `root`.

**Comment by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on 2019-05-15**:
Thanks for your solution

After trying the command, I can run it without sudo. However, the same errors still occur.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
Which errors?

**Comment by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on 2019-05-15**:
Sorry for leaving such a long time.

Well, I still encountered the same errors like

```
...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
of the following names:

  catkinConfig.cmake
  catkin-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
...
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:
I'm not sure, but you may need to `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before starting `colcon_release`.

Just a guess though.

**Comment by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on 2019-05-15**:
In fact, I already did so when installing ros.

Anyway, thanks for your patience.

I think I need to remove everything before trying again. Maybe that would work it out.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:\

> In fact, I already did so when installing ros.

you need to repeat the same statement *every time* you start a new terminal. It is not a one-time setup.

Unless you've added that statement to `$HOME/.bashrc` (if using `bash`).

**Comment by [mangSteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/41557/mangsteve/) on 2019-05-16**:
That works, thanks a lot.